# Ember array data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

What is the proper way to use an array in an Ember data model? Tom Dale points out that ember has "embedded hasOne relationships" in this [comment](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/53#issuecomment-10788301), but I am not able to find any documentation or examples of this in action.

For example I have a `Category` data model like so that has a property called `conditionValues`

```
App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  conditionValues: //this is an array
});
```

I would like to populate this property with an array returned from my server like the one below. `Each category has many condition values`. How might one go about doing this?

```
[condition_values] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [DisplayName] => Brand New
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [DisplayName] => Like New
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [DisplayName] => Very Good
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [DisplayName] => Good
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [DisplayName] => Acceptable
            )

    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Update Feb-26-2014

The code in this answer no longer works since Ember Data 1.0 beta and above.

---

You can handle that in two ways:

First way is to define a model called `App.ConditionValues` and then define a relationship:

```
App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
  //.. your attributes
  conditionValues: DS.hasMany('App.ConditionValues')
});
```

Second way it to create your own [custom transform](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_creating-custom-transformations).

```
DS.RESTAdapter.registerTransform('array', {
  serialize: function(value) {
    if (Em.typeOf(value) === 'array') {
      return value;
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  },
  deserialize: function(value) {
    return value;
  }
});
```

and then in your model:

```
App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
  //.. your attributes
  conditionValues: DS.attr('array')
});
```

Comment: Thanks Teddy Zeenny, which option do you think is the better approach? I like the idea of creating the array type, but if it is not already part of Ember I am sure there is a reason, so kinda leaning toward the first way...

Comment: I'd say it depends on your use case, if the `conditionValues` is actually a standalone model that you want to perform CRUD operations on,  then the first approach is better.  If it's just a read-only array generated on the fly before sending the JSON, then it's safe to go with option 2.

Comment: That makes sense, but why is this not already implemented in Ember? Maybe to prevent confusion

Comment: Because most use cases are the first option. The second scenario is very rare.

Comment: for the lurkers, the current transform docs state ex. 2 should be:
`App.ArrayTransform = DS.Transform.extend({ ... })`